# Android gradle contains signing keys

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin

So I noticed that in android project `build.gradle` file under app folder contains `signing keys` with passwords etc. First of all signed apk will contain all this info in it? And it as well gets pushed to github so it's visible for everyone can I remove it from there? And lastlu why I need all this info there?

Comment: I've come across this too. Signed apk will not contain this afaik since the `build.gradle` file has no business being in your final app. I'd be more worried about GitHub. What I do is I never attach signing to the run configuration for the app (I never run release builds via android studio). You shouldn't need to even since you can just use debug builds and sign off release builds on the fly when you need to release.

Comment: allright so if I remove it from build.gradle before pushing to github will I need to add it back whenever I will make signed apks?

Comment: check for better solution on answer this was marked as duplicate of,